# ¿Como sobreponer mi "dropdown" para que no sea ocultado?

Tags: html

[image: Captura de Pantalla]

Tengo este problema con mi dropdown, donde como podrán ver, es colocado detrás de la tabla y al tratar de desplazar el mouse por el dropdown cuando el cursor se encuentra con la tabla, se oculta nuevamente el dropdown, me gustaría sobreponerlo para que se viera delante de la tabla o bueno, el contenido en general de allí.

**EDIT:**

Ya lo solucione, esto fue lo que hice en CSS, la clase de formtablas(que edita la tabla) le coloque su z-index en -1 (antes estaba en 1) y la clase de dropdown-content, en su apartado de z-index, lo pase a 999.

.formtablas {
    background-color: #ccc;
    opacity: 0.9;
    padding: 15px 25px;
     position:absolute;
    z-index: -1; 
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 999;
}

PD: Disculpen por no pasar el código, es que como no había ningún error en el código no vi la necesidad de postearlo, pero me leeré las normas que debí haber leído antes, gracias.

Comment: Puedes poner tu codigo para poder ayudarte de manera mas facil?

Comment: Debes agregar el código que estás usando, una imagen no nos sirve, **es importante que leas [ask]**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si el dropdown tiene un `position:absolute`, ponle:

```
z-index:999
```

entre más alto el `z-index`, más delante se pondrá el elemento.

Comment: Al dropdown lo subi al 999 y luego a la tabla al 1, pero seguía sucediendo lo mismo, así que coloque el z-index de la tabla a -1 y funciono, gracias =)

Comment: Qué bien, me alegra